# PHPUnit does not automatically detect files in directory

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

So I am trying to create some unit tests in WordPress and I installed PHPUnit 6.5.5(tried various versions up to 7.* which is the latest supported by WP).

The generated phpunit.xml.dist file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory prefix="test-" suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

The tests folder is the default one with bootstrap.php and test-sample.php file:

```
tests
   -- bootstrap.php
   -- test-sample.php
```

However, when I am in my plugin's directory and run `phpunit` I get **No tests executed**.

When I add the test file below the directory as:

```
<file>tests/test-sample.php</file>
```

and then run `phpunit`, I can see the test running.

Shouldn't it automatically detect the directory and files in the testsuite without the need of writing each test file one-by-one in the XML?

**EDIT:** `phpunit -v` output:

```
$ phpunit -v
Installing...
Running as single site... To run multisite, use -c tests/phpunit/multisite.xml
Not running ajax tests. To execute these, use --group ajax.
Not running ms-files tests. To execute these, use --group ms-files.
Not running external-http tests. To execute these, use --group external-http.
PHPUnit 6.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.3.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Configuration: /vagrant/Plugins/Framework/phpunit.xml.dist



Time: 1 second, Memory: 26.00MB
```

**EDIT 2:** bootstrap.php file contents:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPUnit bootstrap file
 */

$_tests_dir = getenv( 'WP_TESTS_DIR' );

if ( ! $_tests_dir ) {
    $_tests_dir = rtrim( sys_get_temp_dir(), '/\\' ) . '/wordpress-tests-lib';
}

if ( ! file_exists( $_tests_dir . '/includes/functions.php' ) ) {
    echo "Could not find $_tests_dir/includes/functions.php, have you run bin/install-wp-tests.sh ?" . PHP_EOL; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    exit( 1 );
}

// Give access to tests_add_filter() function.
require_once $_tests_dir . '/includes/functions.php';

/**
 * Manually load the plugin being tested.
 */
function _manually_load_plugin() {
    require realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..') . '/myplugin/myplugin.php';
}
tests_add_filter( 'muplugins_loaded', '_manually_load_plugin' );

// Start up the WP testing environment.
require $_tests_dir . '/includes/bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: The configuration looks ok, there must be something with enviroment or phpunit itself. What returns bin/phpunit  -v ? Also please try remove leading "./" characters.

Comment: Somehow, it started working. This remains a mystery to me as well. phpunit -v showed as extra the php version(7.30 as well as the phpunit.xml.dist which was the correct path.

Comment: So I am using vagrant and on each vagrant up I get the following error: ```Could not find /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/functions.php, have you run bin/install-wp-tests.sh ?``` Do I need to run ```bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root '' localhost latest``` each time I vagrant up? After running this my unit tests do not run in the VM(No tests found). On my host they appear to load correctly.

Comment: You mentioned `phpunit.xml.dist` while the path displayed with `phpunit -v` is `/vagrant/Plugins/Framework/phpunit.xml`. What's the content of the latter?

Comment: I renamed the file but then switched it back to .dist. The folder I execute `phpunit` is from `/vagrant/Plugins/Framework/` which picks the correct XML.

Answer (score 1):

- **phpunit without command-line options**

You should wonder what is your current working directory when you run `phpunit` without command-line options as you can see in the [phpunit 6.5 doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/textui.html).
If phpunit.xml or phpunit.xml.dist (in that order) exist in the current working directory and --configuration is not used, the configuration will be automatically read from that file.

- **phpunit with command-line options**

If you want to run phpunit from a directory that does not content phpunit.xml (for example your plugin's directory), you'll have to pass the correct path :

`phpunit --configuration /vagrant/Plugins/Framework/phpunit.xml.dist`

As you configured `bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"` in your phpunit.xml.dist, phpunit will look for a `bootstrap.php` file in `/vagrant/Plugins/Framework/tests` directory.

Your bootstrap.php file contains these lines :

`$_tests_dir = getenv( 'WP_TESTS_DIR' );
if ( !$_tests_dir ) $_tests_dir = '/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib';`

I suggest you replace them by :
`$_tests_dir = '/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib';`

You could also add this in your ~/.bash_profile to avoid repeating the replacement :

`export WP_TESTS_DIR='/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib'`

Comment: the configuration file used is the correct one. I can run the tests manually one by one. It seems phpunit cannot find the test files and run them automatically.

Comment: What does your bootstrap.php look like ?

Comment: I have added the bootstrap.php contents on my post. It is basically what `wp scaffold plugin-tests` generates. I have only changed the path to the plugin which should not have any impact as its the same path basically.

Comment: And what do you have in your $WP_CORE_DIR environment variable ?

Comment: Not sure if I do this correctly, but adding `var_dump(getenv( 'WP_CORE_DIR' ));` in bootstrap.php returns `bool(false)`. Tried setting $_tests_dir as you mentioned as well as editing the bash_profile but still no tests are run.

Comment: Seems that your $WP_CORE_DIR is not set. What is your WP trunk ? /srv/www/wordpress-trunk/public_html/src/ ?

Comment: I haven't setup WP trunk, all I did was run the `wp scaffold plugin-test` command. I then run `bin/install-wp-tests.sh` once I log into my vagrant machine so I can run the tests and I get the *No tests executed** error. I have a **/tmp/wordpress** and a **/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib folder**. Could these help define $WP_CORE_DIR so I can run my unit tests?